# CYPRESS - Making the ":contains()" in a filter selector case-insensitive

Tags: filter, cypress, case-insensitive

I am attempting to use the `.filter` command of `cy.get()` to return multiple instances of a DOM object that has the same word, but different cases, and can't get it working.

Eg: I want the following code example to return both `Hello`, `hello` and even `heLLo`

```
cy.get('tbody tr')
  .filter(':contains("hello")')
```

---

**Update**: One further piece of information that may affect things is what I am doing after this.  Here's a beefier piece of code example:

```
cy.get('tbody tr')
  .filter(':contains("hello")')
  .within(() => {
     cy.get('td').then(($rows) => {
        <do stuff>
     };
  };
```

---

Is this even possible?  According to the documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter#Filter-by-text) the text selection is case-sensitive, but I'm hoping there is another option, eg: am I able to use Regex in this instance instead?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right, `.contains(...)` is not the way, it only returns one result, in the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Yields)

> .contains() yields ***the new DOM element*** it found.

One way to filter by text case-insensitive is to use a `.filter()` with callback.

Testing this

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>heLLO</td></tr>
    <tr><td>goodbye</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this test succeeds

```js
cy.get('tbody tr')
  .filter((i, el) => el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes('hello'))
  .should('have.length', 3)             // 3 out of 4 rows
```

or you can add your own pseudo

```js
Cypress.$.expr.pseudos.containsInsensitive = function(a, i, m) {
  return Cypress.$(a).text().toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};

cy.get('tbody tr')
  .filter(':containsInsensitive("hello")')
  .should('have.length', 3)             // 3 out of 4 rows
```

or if you prefer regex

```js
Cypress.$.expr.pseudos.match = function(a, i, m) {
  const expr = m[3].split('/')[1]
  const flags = m[3].split('/')[2]
  const regex = new RegExp(expr, flags)
  return regex.test(Cypress.$(a).text())
};

cy.get('tbody tr')
  .filter(':match(/hello/i)')
  .should('have.length', 3)             // 3 out of 4 rows
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2):

How about you just use `.contains()` then you can pass the case sensitivity flag `matchCase` as `false`. [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Arguments)

```
cy.get('tbody tr').contains('hello', { matchCase: false })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply.  I tried that, but didn't seem to work.  It may be to do with what I am doing with it which I failed to include in the OP.  I have updated it with a bit more information on how it is currently working.  Changing the `.filter` to a `.contains` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've played a bit more.  I don't think `.contains` is going to work.  Correct me if I'm wrong, it seems to return a single (the first?) matching element.  I need an array of matching elements, hence the `.filter`.  Apologies if this wasn't clear in the OP.  

To illustrate the problem:
`.contains('hello', {matchCase: false}).then(($rows) => { cy.log($rows.length)  })` returns a length of 1


`.filter(':contains("hello")').then(($rows) => { cy.log($rows.length) })`
returns a length of 4 (in my application)